# How to limit memory allocation in a Drupal query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a Drupal forum site that has large data in it. For example one forum category has 14,000 threads and has 100,000 comments. Even in my local testing site, it's very laggy. Then when I uploaded it to a live site, it gives this error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 52428800 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 40961 bytes) in /home/fmotors/public_html/development/includes/theme.inc on line 1494
```

So it has something to do with increasing the memory limit, or to not query all the threads at once. But I don't know how to do either of them. Here's the code which flagged the error above:

```
function theme_render_template($template_file, $variables) {
  extract($variables, EXTR_SKIP);               // Extract the variables to a local namespace
  ob_start();                                   // Start output buffering
  include DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . $template_file;   // Include the template file
  return ob_get_clean();                        // End buffering and return its contents
}
```

The call to `ob_start()` is on line 1494. By the way, I'm using the advance forum module of Drupal.

Comment: Return less data.  Without seeing your query, it's hard to give details.

Comment: If Drupal is anything like Wordpress, it could be trying to hold all comments in memory even if the view you are using is paginated. If that is the problem, then searching for "drupal php reduce memory usage" would be a good first step. That said, 50M may be too little for a complex PHP app: try configuring 64 or 80M and see if that works?

Comment: @halfer where to configure that 50M to 80M? and how do i not query all comments at once? yes they are paginated and i suspect that what you say is true about querrying all at once even if it's paginated.

Comment: The memory allocation for PHP is set up in your php.ini file, using a key called `memory_limit`. Do you run on a server where you have control over that? Some shared hosts permit this to be modified per-user, some do not. If you don't have access to that, you can sometimes set it in your `.htaccess` file, using something like `php_value memory_limit 64M`. (I've no idea about the memory efficiency of Drupal, sorry - never used it).

Answer (score 0):

in your configuraion or index file set

```
ini_set('memory_limit', 0);
```

Comment: Does this just paper over the problem instead of fixing it? Now there's another potential bug where the script could use up too much system memory and cause even harder to track bugs.